# JUnit && Mockito

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, junit, mockito

I have this method that I want to test

```
     private Connection con;
     private Statement set;
     private ResultSet rs;

     public void actualizarJugador(String nombre) {
            try {
                set = con.createStatement();
                set.executeUpdate("UPDATE Jugadores SET votos=votos+1 WHERE nombre " + " LIKE '%" + nombre + "%'");
                rs.close();
                set.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // No modifica la tabla
                System.out.println("No modifica la tabla");
                System.out.println("El error es: " + e.getMessage());
            }
        }
```

How can I do it? How can I test a method that does not return anything?

Thanks

Comment: what do you want to test? when should your test pass and when should it fail? ps. your code is leaking resources and printing on stdout on exception, neither of which are recommended

Comment: Creating an SQL query by combining unsanitized strings causes trouble if the input string (e.g. `nombre`) is allowed to have special characters. You should consider using `PreparedStatement` unless you are absolutely sure your current usage of `Statement` is safe.

Answer (score 0):

the method has a side effect, it changes the calue of `votos` under a certain condition. To test that, you need to query your database and check that the value was actually updated. You can also check that values not fulfilling the where-condition are not updated. To do that you should query the database before and after you call your method, and compare the values with each other.

Answer (score 0):

I have this example code

```
import java.sql.*;

public class ModeloDatos {

    private Connection con;
    private Statement set;
    private ResultSet rs;

    public void abrirConexion() {

        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");

            // Con variables de entorno
            String dbHost = System.getenv().get("DATABASE_HOST");
            String dbPort = System.getenv().get("DATABASE_PORT");
            String dbName = System.getenv().get("DATABASE_NAME");
            String dbUser = System.getenv().get("DATABASE_USER");
            String dbPass = System.getenv().get("DATABASE_PASS");

            String url = dbHost + ":" + dbPort + "/" + dbName;
            con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, dbUser, dbPass);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            // No se ha conectado
            System.out.println("No se ha podido conectar");
            System.out.println("El error es: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    public boolean existeJugador(String nombre) {
        boolean existe = false;
        String cad;
        try {
            set = con.createStatement();
            rs = set.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM Jugadores");
            while (rs.next()) {
                cad = rs.getString("Nombre");
                cad = cad.trim();
                if (cad.compareTo(nombre.trim()) == 0) {
                    existe = true;
                }
            }
            rs.close();
            set.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // No lee de la tabla
            System.out.println("No lee de la tabla");
            System.out.println("El error es: " + e.getMessage());
        }
        return (existe);
    }

    public void actualizarJugador(String nombre) {
        try {
            set = con.createStatement();
            set.executeUpdate("UPDATE Jugadores SET votos=votos+1 WHERE nombre " + " LIKE '%" + nombre + "%'");
            rs.close();
            set.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // No modifica la tabla
            System.out.println("No modifica la tabla");
            System.out.println("El error es: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    public void insertarJugador(String nombre) {
        try {
            set = con.createStatement();
            set.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO Jugadores " + " (nombre,votos) VALUES ('" + nombre + "',1)");
            rs.close();
            set.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // No inserta en la tabla
            System.out.println("No inserta en la tabla");
            System.out.println("El error es: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    public void ponerVotosCero() {
        try {
            set = con.createStatement();
            set.executeUpdate("UPDATE Jugadores SET votos=0 where votos>0");
            rs.close();
            set.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // No modifica la tabla
            System.out.println("Poner votos a cero. No modifica la tabla");
            System.out.println("El error es: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }


    public void cerrarConexion() {
        try {
            con.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }

}
```

With this test, it should be something similar

```
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.*;

public class ModeloDatosTest {
    @Test
    public void testExisteJugador() {
        System.out.println("Prueba de existeJugador");
        String nombre = "";
        ModeloDatos instance = new ModeloDatos();
        boolean expResult = false;
        boolean result = instance.existeJugador(nombre);
        assertEquals(expResult, result);
        //fail("Fallo forzado.");
    }
}
```

Comment: please don't add your code as an answer and rather edit your existing question.